# What can we say about the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a symmetric, orthogonal matrix $$J_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu} - 2 \frac{z_\mu z_\nu}{z^2}, $$ where $z_\mu$ are real numbers, $z_0 > 0$ and $z^2 = \delta^{\alpha\beta} z_\alpha z_\beta$.

Since this matrix is symmetric and orthogonal, we certainly know that its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.

However, can we say something about the number of positive and negative eigenvalues?

Comment: Its the jacobian of a coordinate transformation

Comment: Hint: $J - I$ has rank $1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't see how that'll help me. Could you give some more explanation?

Comment: Clarification questions: What is $z_0$? Are you summing over $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: $z_0 = z_{\mu = 0}$, where I'm assuming that the indices go from $0$ to $d$. Yes summing over $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{z}= (z_0, \dots, z_d)^T$ and let $\mathbf{w}$ be any vector that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$. Compute $J \mathbf{z}$ and $J \mathbf{w}$.  *Don't use coordinate notation. Use vector and matrix notatioon throughout.*

Comment: Your $J$ is a [Householder reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Answer (score 0):

If $z$ is a column vector of $R^n$ of length one,  the matrix $J=I-2z z^T$ is the representative matrix of the symmetry changing $x$ into its symmetric $x'$ with respect to the plane $P=\{y; \langle y,z\rangle=0\}.$

$P$ is stable by $J$, and  $Jz=-z$. Consider the orthonormal basis $(z,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$ ; the representative matrix of the symmetry in this new basis is $\mathrm{diag (-1,1,\ldots,1)}.$